# Elasticity problem: compression of a runner's femur

Tags: homework-and-exercises, elasticity

This is a homework question. As such, please do not tell me what the correct answer to the question itself is. I know how to solve the problem, but I'm stuck on one preliminary step that is necessary to piecing together a solution. Here is the prompt:

> The normal force of the ground on the foot can reach three times a runner's body weight when the foot strikes the pavement. By what amount does the 52-cm-long femur of an $67 kg$ runner compress at this moment? The cross-section area of the bone of the femur can be taken as $5.2×10−4 \space m^2$ and its Young's modulus is $1.6×10^{10} \space N/m^2$.

**What I know**:

A typical spring has a retracting force defined as $F_{sp} = k\Delta L$. However, uniformly solid materials like a bone or a rod can also be modeled as springs, since they also slightly compress under pressure. For such solids, the equation is very similar, except it includes Young's Modulus, the cross-sectional area, and the length of the spring:

$F_{sp} = \frac{Y\times A}{L}\Delta L$

We are given Y, A, and L. We need to find $\Delta L$. To do so, we need to determine $F_{sp}$ from the problem statement. In particular, we're told that in the moment that the foot strikes the ground, the normal force pushing up on it is three times the weight of the foot.

**What I'm struggling to understand**:

In my initial attempt, I lost points on this homework because I solved it under the assumption that the spring force equals $2mg$, which, when combined with the normal force $mg$, would generate a net upwards force of $3mg$. Using this approach, I got an answer of 0.0082 cm.

Do I treat the spring force as part of the normal force pushing up, or is it to be considered as a separate force that adds to the normal force?

Comment: I feel a need to pick... the femur starts at the knee, so when you are given the normal force at the foot you don't know the force on the femur - it will be lower, in part because it doesn't support all the weight of the runner (namely, not the lower part of one leg) and in part because there is flexing at the knee. I assume the person who set the homework didn't care - but I do.

Answer (score 1):

What they are saying is that, soon after the foot hits the ground, the femur is supporting a compressive load equal to 3x the runner's body weight.  Before the runner's foot landed, the femur was supporting a compressive force of zero.

I might also add that the normal force of the ground on the foot when the foot lands is not equal to mg.  It is only equal to mg if the runner is at static equilibrium in the vertical direction.  The normal force when the foot hits the ground is much closer to 3 mg.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

How to interpret the wording of the question
The normal (as in perpendicular to the ground) force of 3mg acts upwards at the foot. The runner's weight acts downwards.

Where you went wrong
Both these forces cause compression of the femur, they should be added together to determine the total compressive force.

Comment: So in this case, $F_{sp} = 3mg$?

Comment: Why should these forces be added together? It is not obvious to me.

Comment: Okay, I figured it out. $F_{sp}$ does equal $3mg$ because the normal force is the only force causing the compression. Thus, $F_{sp} = n$. I solved it like that and got the correct answer. They're not additive.